# PushMatrix and PopMatrix in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want the second line to be original color (white). I know I could write 'color: 1,1,1,1' but I would like to use PushMatrix and PopMatrix but it does not work. Where to place PushMatrix and PopMatrix?

Here my sample code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        PushMatrix:
        color: 1,0,0,1
        canvas:

            Line:
                points: self.x, self.y, self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height
        PopMatrix:
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Line:
                points: self.x, self.y, self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height
""")

class LabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color isn't a Matrix instruction, so PushMatrix and PopMatrix do not affect it. The simple solution is to simply use a second Color instruction.

Also, your syntax is invalid - PushMatrix and PopMatrix are canvas instructions that can only appear under the canvas section in kv.

Edit: To be clear, Color is another canvas instruction that you need to add, e.g.

```
Color:
    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
```